# VBA to click on popup sweet-container's button using className

Tags: html, css, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have tried to click a Button in IE Sweetalert popup by using querySelector and GetElementBytagName, ClassName. The HTML of the popup as shown below.

```
<div class="sweet-alert show-sweet-alert hideSweetAlert visible" tabindex="-1" style="width: 500px; padding: 20px; margin-left: -250px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; margin-top: -148px;">
<hr>
<button class="confirm" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-left-color: rgb(26, 179, 148); border-right-color: rgb(26, 179, 148);">Yes</button>
<button class="cancel" style="display: inline-block; background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);">No</button></div>
```

selectors of the button as below.

body > div.sweet-container > div.sweet-alert.show-sweet-alert.visible > button.cancel

body > div.sweet-container > div.sweet-alert.show-sweet-alert.visible > button.confirm

I tried querySelector no error but nothing happen.

```
IE.document.querySelector("button.cancel").Click

IE.document.querySelector("button.confirm").Click
```

and also I have tried

```
Dim btntg As Object
For Each btntg In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If InStr(btntg.outerHTML, "confirm") > 0 Then

        btntg.Click
        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

**I did not get any reaction on button and there is no error.**

I need help on it.

Comment: Is there an url we can visit to reproduce this?

Comment: No @QHarr  I could only find some javascript behind this.

Comment: I meant, is there a public url associated with the html you have shown?

Comment: @QHarr There is no public URL available, only access credentials are available.

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to add a listener for the button click event, if this is the case, you can use [addEventListener() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp).

Comment: @XudongPeng I'm trying to automate the webpage with VBA.

Comment: I created a simple test and I found that IE.document.querySelector("button.cancel") can work normally, this is my [test example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM28q.png) and [test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hW8B.png). If possible, can you provide more details?